# C# в классе ArrayList есть два одноименных метода, возвращающих разные значения. WTF?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, методы

Недавно рыскал по object browser'у, и увидел такую картину[image: Изображение]

Есть два одноименных метода ToArray, один из которых возвращает массив object'ов, а другой экземпляр класса Array. Как такое возможно? Перерыл пол гугла, MDSN говорит, что прегружать методы по возвращаемым значениям нельзя, на всех форумах пишут тоже самое, когда народ спрашивает "а можно ли так?". Но тут же в стандартной библиотеке я вижу такую картину. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто в теме, как это реализованно, потому что я читал, что стандартная библиотека типо не подчиняется правилам, использует функции от WinAPI и т.п.

Comment: ну так там не только возвращаемое значение меняется, но и входное добавляется.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал что так можно, странно просто что на эту тему нету особо ответов, поэтому и засоряю StackOverFlow :)

Comment: [вот немножко инфы](http://plssite.ru/csharp/csharp_methods_overload_article.html) где это встречаеться

Comment: @AlexChirita ну так это уже перегрузка и получается ибо сигнатура поменялась. чёж нельзя-то)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: А почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD мне иногда лениво писать полно. Но и никому не запрещается взять коммент и поделиться им в ответе)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напомню, что перегрузка методов позволяет создавать методы с одним и тем же именем, но с разным списком аргументов. Причем возвращаемое значение не учитывается, а отличаться должны именно аргументы методов.

Если посмотреть на метод `ToArray`, то видно, что один метод не имеет входных параметров, а другой - имеет. Сигнатура поменялась, а, значит, можно сделать вывод, что тут имеет место быть перегрузка.

Так что вполне всё корректно, даже если бы возвращаемое значение второго метода был тоже `object[]`.